Solve the heat equation with rare boundary conditions.
The problem is - with $x \in \left(0, L\right)$
and $t >0$ - :
\begin{align*}
u_t-k^2u_{xx} & =0
\\
u(x,0) & = g(x)
\\
u_x(0,t)-hu(0,t) & =0
\\
u_x(L,t)+hu(L,t) & =0
\end{align*}
where $h\geq 0$ (the case h=0 is easy, the problem is h>0) For h>0:
I tried to solve it with the method of separation of variables.
Suppose the solution has the form $u=X(x)T(t)$.
By the boundary conditions, we have
\begin{align*}
X'(0)-hX(0)=0 \quad&(*)\\
X'(L)+hX(L)=0 \quad&(**)
\end{align*}
And the dpe
$\frac{X''}{X}=\frac{T'}{k^2T}=-\lambda$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
X''+\lambda X=0 \\
T'+k^2\lambda T=0 
\end{align*}
Here I have problems discarding the lambda values
if $\lambda<0$
The solution is $X=acosh(\sqrt{-\lambda}x)+bsinh(\sqrt{-\lambda}x)$
From (*) $b\sqrt{-\lambda=}h\alpha=0$ So $ a=\frac{b\sqrt{-\lambda}}{h}$
From(**) $[-\lambda \frac{b}{h}+bh]sinh(\sqrt{-\lambda }L)+[2\sqrt{-\lambda}b]cosh(\sqrt{-\lambda }L)=0$
Here I have no idea what I can do
For $lambda=0$ the solution is $X=a+bx$
From (*) b-ha=0
From (**) b+h(a+bL)=0
Then we have $b=0$, so $ah=0$, $a=0$. The solution is trivial.
All the problem would be different if in the last condition it was $u_x(L,t)-hu(L,t)=0$, here I can solve all the cases of lambda.

This set of BC is not "rare". It is just Robin BC, which describes a pretty common physical phenomenon: how fast the heat is transferred on the boundary (flux) of a rod is proportional to the temperature.

Expect to not be able to find $\lambda$ in closed form in this case.  But Sturm-Liouville theory will tell you what sign $\lambda$ can be.

Sorry, this is not intended to be a complete elaboration with a derivation of all the formulas.
But I would like to show the general solution for this case (with assistance of Mathematica):
$$u(x,t)=\sqrt{2}\cdot \underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\frac{\sqrt{K_n-h^2}\cdot e^{-k^2 t K_n}\cdot \left(h \sin \left(x \sqrt{K_n}\right)+\sqrt{K_n} \cos \left(x \sqrt{K_n}\right)\right) }{\sqrt{2 h K_n+L K_n^2-h^4 L-2 h^3}} I_n$$
with
$$I_n=\sqrt{2}\cdot \int_{0}^{L} \left[g(x)\cdot \frac{\sqrt{K_n-h^2}\cdot \left(h \sin \left(x \sqrt{K_n}\right)+\sqrt{K_n} \cos \left(x \sqrt{K_n}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{-\left(\left(h^2-K_n\right) (L K_n+h (h L+2))\right)}}\right]\, dx$$
and $K_n$ is the $n^{th}$ root of the equation
$$\left(K_n-h^2\right)\cdot \sin \left(L \sqrt{K_n}\right)=2 h \sqrt{K_n}\cdot \cos \left(L \sqrt{K_n}\right)$$
Example with parameters
$L=1.0, k=0.6, h=1.0$ and initial condition
$$g(x)=\begin{cases} 
    1+h x, & 0 \le x \le \frac{L}{2}\\
    1+h(L-x), & \frac{L}{2} < x\le L
\end{cases}$$
Here is a MATLAB implementation: MSE_Q4993797
Visualization of the example:

